# Golang map json to struct

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a JSON which I need to extract the data out of it using a struct:

I am trying to map it to the below struct:

```
type Message struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Values []struct {
        Value int `json:"value,omitempty"`
        Comments int `json:"comments,omitempty"`
        Likes    int `json:"likes,omitempty"`
        Shares   int `json:"shares,omitempty"`
    } `json:"values"`
}
```

This is my json:

```
[{
        "name": "organic_impressions_unique",
        "values": [{
            "value": 8288
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "post_story_actions_by_type",
        "values": [{
            "shares": 234,
            "comments": 838,
            "likes": 8768
        }]
    }]
```

My questions are:

1. How to structure my struct?
2. How to read the name, values and comments?

So far I couldn't read the data using the below code:

```
msg := []Message{}
getJson("https://json.url", msg)
println(msg[0])
```

the getJson function:

```
func getJson(url string, target interface{}) error {
    r, err := myClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I need to know how to structure my struct and how to read the name, values and comments, etc...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I guess it wasn't clear, I updated the question

Comment: Have you written any code that tries to use your struct definition? Does it work? Does it fail? Does it report an error?

Comment: I edited my question to mention the code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your struct is correct. All you need is <s>love</s> to use [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) function with a correct target object which is slice of `Message` instances: `[]Message{}`

[Correct unmarshaling](https://play.golang.org/p/SISWI9RGne):

```
type Message struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Values []struct {
        Value    int `json:"value,omitempty"`
        Comments int `json:"comments,omitempty"`
        Likes    int `json:"likes,omitempty"`
        Shares   int `json:"shares,omitempty"`
    } `json:"values"`
}

func main() {
    input := []byte(`
[{
    "name": "organic_impressions_unique",
    "values": [{
        "value": 8288
    }]
    }, {
        "name": "post_story_actions_by_type",
        "values": [{
            "shares": 234,
            "comments": 838,
            "likes": 8768
        }]
    }]
`)

    messages := []Message{} // Slice of Message instances
    json.Unmarshal(input, &messages)
    fmt.Println(messages)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON seems to be an array. Just unmarshall it to a slice. Something like:

```
var messages []Message
err := json.Unmarshal(json, &messages)
```

Should work.

Comment: `json` inside the unmarshal stands for what? the url?

Comment: check the getJson function in my question plz, I added it now

Comment: json inside the unmarshal stands for json blob in your question which you fetch somehow seems

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be any help now, but i've recently written utility for generating exact go type from json input: https://github.com/m-zajac/json2go

For json from first post it generates this struct:

```
type Object struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Values  []struct {
        Comments    *int    `json:"comments,omitempty"`
        Likes       *int    `json:"likes,omitempty"`
        Shares      *int    `json:"shares,omitempty"`
        Value       *int    `json:"value,omitempty"`
    }   `json:"values"`
}
```

You can decode data to this struct like this:

```
var docs []Object
if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &docs); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```